# Debugger doesn't show new variable in stack frame

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, stack

Can someone tell me, why the debugger doesn't show variable `j` in stack frame(Using IntelliJ IDEA)?

```
for (int i = 0 ;  i < 10; i++) {
        int j = 100;
    }
```

when `i = 0`, variable `j` should be created once, then, being removed from the stack, then `i = 2`, j should be loaded into the stack, but IntelliJ debug tool doesn't show the creation of `j` once, Where is the problem? Thank you

Screenshot:

1. [image]
2. [image]
3. [image]

There is a tool, please try it out https://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/java_visualize/#

Comment: Is it possible that the optimiser is removing it since you don't do anything with it?

Try adding a variable outside the loop - k, and inside the loop create j as usual and then add j to k each time through.

Comment: @Rick you are correct, IntelliJ Team has given the reply below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This variable is not used and `javac` compiler optimizes the bytecode by completely removing it. You can add some usage for the variable, like log it so `System.out` and then you should be able to see it in the debugger.

Comment: Thank you  Crazycoder, you are really active, thank you, 10 minutes ago. i was reading your words:  use the `e` to expand the UML in intellij